# Inline-block parent - no taller than children?

Tags: html, css

I have an `inline-block` div that I'd like to be no taller than its children. Is this achievable?

Here's an illustration of what's happening at the moment (color added):

[image]

```css
.agenda-btn-container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
}

#agenda-view-start-btn {
  background-color: gray;
}

#agenda-view-previous-btn {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<a class='agenda-btn-container' id='agenda-view-btn-container-previous' href='#'>
  <i id="agenda-view-start-btn" class='i-vb-angle-double-left i-space--right'></i>
  <span id="agenda-view-previous-btn">Previous</span>
</a>
```

Basically, my desired end-product would eliminate the pink space at the top and bottom, making the parent the height of `#agenda-view-previous-btn`.  Initially, I was able to do this just fine by setting the parent to `display: inline`, but unfortunately, due to a cross-browser issue, the parent needs to be `inline-block` (or `block` would work, too, but I'm not sure that makes much of a difference here).

Comment: Hm, running your code, I don't see any pink - which is what I expected.

Comment: I don't see any pink either.

Comment: Because he or she has a line-height on the body, then inline/inline-block elements will use that. I answered this.

Comment: @Christina How do you know that?

Comment: Because most CSS design is done with a reset (normalize for example) and unless a user designer has poor typography aesthetics, there is a line-height on a parent, usually the body.

Comment: @Christina That's only a guess on your part. In my 13 years, I've never used a reset and discourage anyone from using one. Let's not assume anything.

Comment: Seriously, nearly all CSS uses normalize or at least there is a line-height on some parent, usually the body. And 18 years for me.

Comment: Not a guess. He or she can use my answer and see that it works.

Comment: Indeed, there was a line-height being set on the body. Nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add line-height: normal to reset the inherited line height.

```
.agenda-btn-container{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: pink;
    line-height: normal;
}
```